# React | Package.Json | "proxy" Not Working when deployed on Cloud - Vercel

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, rest, google-app-engine, frontend

I created a basic React app with 'create-react-app' and a simple Spring Boot backend service. In the react application I added 'proxy' to the package.json file which points to the Spring Boot backend that is deployed on railway.

"proxy":  https://has-backend-production.up.railway.app

When testing locally React calls Sprint Boot Rest Api's through the proxy and everything works. When I deploy it to Vercel, the proxy isn't working. I tested Spring Boot service(on Railway) with my local React instance and things work as expected. When I deploy the React app to Vercel(after running NPM RUN BUILD), the proxy is not working. It is giving the following error

[image]

Github Repo's

Frontend - https://github.com/harmanmalhotra/HAS-Frontend

Backend - https://github.com/harmanmalhotra/HAS-Backend

package.json file - https://github.com/harmanmalhotra/HAS-Frontend/blob/master/package.json

My website link - https://has-frontend.vercel.app/

If anyone knows how to solve this issue, please help. I am stuck on it for a long time.

Comment: Same issue I am having, Node with react, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can create a config object and pick base_url based on the env. On local, it will pick development url and on Railway it will use production.

```
const configs = {
  development: {
    SERVER_URI: 'localhost:8080',
  },
  production: {
    SERVER_URI: 'Railway_URI',
  },
};

module.exports.config = configs[process.env.NODE_ENV];
```

Then use axios like this

```
axios.get(`${config.SERVER_URI}/name`).then(res=>({...}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem today.
Solution that worked for me:

There is a built-in environment variable called NODE_ENV. You can read it from process.env.NODE_ENV. When you run npm start, it is always equal to 'development',  and when you run npm run build to make a production bundle, it is always equal to 'production'.

So, you don't need proxy, try the code below in your components with server url.

```
const rootUrl = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 
'https://newway.herokuapp.com' : 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
```

example of request:

```
const response = await axios.post(`${rootUrl}/api/pupils/`, userData)
```

link that might help: https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/proxy-does-not-work-with-the-react-build-version/494653/4